# Regex for Hash tag but without a # in href

Tags: php, regex

**What I tried**:

http://regexr.com?38d9s

`#\w+` to match any Alpha-numeric starting with #

and replacing it with:

`<a href="/$&" />$&</a>`

I want to get rid of # in href area of a tag and keep it as a link text, i.e. between starting and ending tags. Check the example below.

**What I want**

if the sentence is:

> Lorem ipsum #set amet #dolor

then, I want the output to be:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="/set">#set</a> amet <a href="/dolor">#dolor</a>
```

I am using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) without any delimiters.

What I already have :

`preg_replace('/(?<=#)\w+/', '<a href="/\\0" />\\0</a>', $comment)`

it gives me:

```
Lorem ipsum #<a href="/set">set</a> amet #<a href="/dolor">dolor</a>
```

and NOT

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="/set">#set</a> amet <a href="/dolor">#dolor</a>
```

Notice the position of #

Comment: Match `#(\w+)` and replace `<a href="/hash/$1">$&</a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capturing group.

Replace:

```
#(\w+)
```

with

```
<a href="/$1" />$&</a>
```

`$1` is replaced with captured group 1 (word part)

---

In PHP:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', '<a href="/\1" />\0</a>',
                         $sentence);
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it with preg_replace, please?

Comment: Nope, getting the same output.

Comment: @KarmicDice, I saw your updated question. It use lookbehind assertion. Which is different what I answer (I used capturing group)

Comment: @KarmicDice, Did you see the demo in my previous comment? (It was updated) http://ideone.com/NaBN4d

Comment: @KarmicDice, If you want to use lookbehind assertion, you need to prepend `#` explicitly: `preg_replace('/(?<=#)\w+/', '<a href="/\0" />#\0</a>', $comment)`

Comment: @falsetru: No, that is incorrect. It'll produce the output `Lorem ipsum ##set amet ##dolor`, which is not what the OP is looking for :)

Comment: yes, not the comment but the code in the answer worked.

Comment: +1. I deleted my answer was it was similar to yours. Although I still have no idea how this satisfies @Karmic's requirement in the original question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`$replaced=preg_replace("/\#([\w\d]+)/ui",'<a href="/\1">\0</a>',$text);`

I suggest to you use this. On falsetru's answers he is using \w. It means it will match only alphanumeric chars in English language. If you use \w\d it will match all utf-8 chars begining with #.

Comment: `\d` is redundant. `\w` matches digits too. (alpha **numeric**) BTW, `\w` not only match alphanumeric characters, but it also matches `_`. See [PHP: Escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).